# LinkedIn API "The update mapping to user's update-key cannot be processed."

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I am attempting to get user comments on a network update. Some updates fail with the error "The update mapping to user's update-key cannot be processed."

I'm getting the updates from `people/~/network/updates`. Then I'm using the updateKey returned to query `people/~/network/updates/key={updateKey}/update-comments`.

One of the updates giving me this error is a company update so I tried `companies/{company_id}/updates/key={update_key}/update-comments` but It gave the same error.

What exactly does it mean by the key can't be processed and what do I need to do to get the comments?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Using the REST Console they link to from the developer site I can pull a list of company updates. But when I try to get the list of likes or comments using the API call provided by the REST console, it returns this error.